# Iterate over (item, others) in a list

Tags: python, sequence, python-itertools, complement

Suppose I have a list:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

How can I iterate over the list, taking each item along with its complement from the list?  That is,

```
for item, others in ...
    print(item, others)
```

would print

```
0 [1, 2, 3]
1 [0, 2, 3]
2 [0, 1, 3]
3 [0, 1, 2]
```

Ideally I'm looking for a concise expression that I can use in a comprehension.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is quite easy and understandable:

```
for index, item in enumerate(l):
    others = l[:index] + l[index+1:]
```

You *could* make an iterator out of this if you insist:

```
def iter_with_others(l):
    for index, item in enumerate(l):
        yield item, l[:index] + l[index+1:]
```

Giving it's usage:

```
for item, others in iter_with_others(l):
    print(item, others)
```

Comment: This works well and is exactly what ecatmur asked for, but seems an exercise in gratuitous list creation.  It could perform quite badly with larger lists.  I wonder if it might be better to create some sort of wrapper object that provides a view into the original list.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: yes, but I'll leave this as an excercise for the reader unless there is a huge demand.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question, it is possible to use `itertools.combinations` exploiting the fact that the result is emitted in lexicographical order:

```
from itertools import combinations
zip(l, combinations(reversed(l), len(l) - 1))
```

However, this is fairly obscure; nightcracker's solution is a *lot* easier to understand for the reader!

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
>>> [(i, [j for j in L if j != i]) for i in L]
[(0, [1, 2, 3]), (1, [0, 2, 3]), (2, [0, 1, 3]), (3, [0, 1, 2])]
```

OK, that's a gazillion of tests and @nightcracker's solution is likely more efficient, but eh...

Comment: You could use generator expressions instead of the list comprehensions and thereby avoid creating unnecessary lists as @StevenRumbalski had dreamed about.

Comment: Yes, I could use a generator for the whole expression, but not for the inner loop: the OP wanted to print lists, not generators..

Comment: Right, at least in his example. The question is whether that is really what he wants to do with the results. But he can decide that for himself.